# What is the correct term for software whose source code is available only to read?

Tags: proprietary-code, terminology

The software is distributed under these terms:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
> of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to read
> the Software only. Permission is hereby NOT GRANTED to use, copy, modify,
> merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software.

This license does not pass Open Source Definition.
Is there any other term besides "proprietary" which can be used to describe this approach for distributing source code?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109801/discussion-on-question-by-andreoss-what-is-the-correct-term-for-software-whose-s).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Source available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-available_software) is a common term used to describe such licenses.

Comment: "Source visible" is also common.